nested symbol reached the end, then next frame or scene
I want to make a nested symbol to reach the current frame, which is at the end, then play and/or stop to next frame or scene.
if (marioHead_SmashandBash.currentFrame == 95){
    gotoAndStop("Beginning");
}

